# How to validate assertion in verify callback of passport SAML strategy during saml/callback?

Tags: node.js, saml, passport-saml

This is Sample code I got from passport-saml documentation. Instead of checking email id I want to validate saml assertion, which in turn will indicate that user is authenticated at idp as well, right? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks...

```js
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
[...]

passport.use(
  new SamlStrategy(
    {
      path: "/login/callback",
      entryPoint:
        "https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php",
      issuer: "passport-saml",
      cert: "fake cert", // cert must be provided
    },
    function (profile, done) {
      // for signon
      findByEmail(profile.email, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    },
    function (profile, done) {
      // for logout
      findByNameID(profile.nameID, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
```

I have found this from some sources, is this the correct finding to achieve the requirement?

```js
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
const xmlCrypto = require('xml-crypto');
const xmlDom = require('xmldom');

passport.use(new SamlStrategy({
  // SAML strategy configuration
}, function(profile, done) {
  // Validate SAML signature
  const isValidSignature = validateSamlSignature(profile);

  if (!isValidSignature) {
    return done(new Error('Invalid SAML signature'));
  }

  // Continue with other verification logic and user creation
  // ...

  if (authenticationIsSuccessful) {
    // User is authenticated
    const user = /* Construct user object based on SAML attributes */;
    done(null, user);
  } else {
    // User authentication failed
    done(new Error('User authentication failed'));
  }
}));

function validateSamlSignature(profile) {
  const signature = profile.getAssertionXml().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Signature")[0];
  const xml = profile.getSamlResponseXml();

  const sig = new xmlCrypto.SignedXml();
  sig.keyInfoProvider = {
    getKeyInfo: function (key) {
      return "<X509Data></X509Data>";
    },
    getKey: function (keyInfo) {
      // Implement key retrieval logic based on your configuration
      // For example, load IdP's public key from a file or configuration
      const publicKey = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n... (IdP's public key) ...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
      return publicKey;
    }
  };

  sig.loadSignature(signature.toString());
  return sig.checkSignature(xml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@node-saml/passport-saml verify among other thing signature on behalf of you during autenticate invocation (during processing of SAML autnresponse which IdP delivered via front channel HTTP POST binding). I.e. signature(s) are already verified prior your callback function is invocated.

1. https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/blob/v4.0.4/src/strategy.ts#L60
2. https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/blob/v4.0.4/src/strategy.ts#L178
3. https://github.com/node-saml/node-saml/blob/v4.0.5/src/saml.ts#L667-L823
4. and if signature(s) were correct among other checks it (passport-saml) hands over control to your callback function https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/blob/v4.0.4/src/strategy.ts#L152-L156

If you are new to the SAML 2.0 consider studying it before using it at production because it has numerous pitfalls and evaluate SAML libraries capabilities against information from these documents in order to determine if those/your choice meets requirements (passport-saml lacks for example XML schema validation which would be one additional layer of security and it lacks mandatory recipient validation meaning that it is not spec compliant). Here are some good documents:

1. Assertions and Protocols for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0
   OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf
2. Profiles for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0
   OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf
3. Security and Privacy Considerations for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0
   OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-sec-consider-2.0-os.pdf
4. Metadata for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0
   OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf
5. and this: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SAML_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html